# Strtok and Char*

Tags: c++, strtok

I have a simple code where Iam trying to go through a `char*` and spit it into separate words.  Here is the simple code I have.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
   char * string1 = "- This is a test string";
   char * character_pointer;
   std::cout << "Splitting stringinto tokens:" << string1 << std::endl;
   character_pointer = strtok (string1," ");
   while (character_pointer != NULL)
   {
       printf ("%s\n", character_pointer);
       character_pointer = strtok (NULL, " ");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I am getting an error that will not allow me to do this.

So my question is, how do I go through and find each word in a `char*`.  For my actual program I am working on, one of my libraries returns a paragraph of words as a `const char*` and I need to stem each word using a stemming algorithm (I know how to do this, I just do not know how to send each individual word to the stemmer).  If someone could just solve how to get the example code to work, I will be able to figure it out.  All of the examples online use a `char[]` for `string1` instead of a `char*` and I cannot do that.

Comment: Don't use `strtok`.  It's hopelessly broken, and in C++, there are much better solutions using algorithms in the standard library.

Comment: This isn't `C++` but primarily `C`.

Comment: @DumbCoder I have never used C and am trying to use this in C++ so I apoligize if I got that wrong.  James what would be a better way of solving this problem?

Comment: @JamesKanze, how would one go about this with C++ prior to C++11? I have tried to replace strtok for tokenizing but never been able to do so without also getting a performance hit. I guess the fact that strtok re-uses the already allocated string makes it quite fast.

Comment: why do you mix C and C++ like this? In C use printf and in C++ use cout

Comment: @scy7he C++11 doesn't add much here.  You'd use the algorithms in `<algorithm>` (things like `std::find_first_of`, for example), and possibly the two iterator constructor of `std::string`.

Comment: also, you must read the error and fix it to make it work. If you cannot fix then post the error here

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest (codewise) way I know to split a string in c++:

```
std::string string1 = "- This is a test string";
std::string word;
std::istringstream iss(string1);
// by default this splits on any whitespace
while(iss >> word) {
    std::cout << word << '\n';
}
```

or like this if you want to specify a delimiter.

```
while(std::getline(iss, word, ' ')) {
    std::cout << word << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways you could do this in C++.

If space is your delimited then you can get the tokens this way:

```
std::string text = "- This is a test string";
std::istringstream ss(text);
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::back_inserter<std::vector<std::string>>(tokens));
```

You can also tokenize the string in C++ using regular expressions.

```
std::string text = "- This is a test string";
std::regex pattern("\\s+");
std::sregex_token_iterator it(std::begin(text), std::end(text), pattern, -1);
std::sregex_token_iterator end;
for(; it != end; ++it)
{
   std::cout << it->str() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that `<regex>` support was added to libstdc++ in [version 4.9](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html) of gcc.

Comment: I didn't see any gcc reference, but yes, that is true.

Comment: Your assumption also doesn't hold. OP's code breaks at space, yours at anything that isn't alphabetic or a hyphen.

Comment: Yes, thank's for pointing that. I have updated the answer. The new version should be correct.

Comment: For something simple like he's doing (and in fact, most of what `strtok` can do), regular expressions are overkill, and using `istream` is very overweight, and not very flexible.  Things like `std::find_first_of`, `std::search` and so on, are much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a corrected version, try it out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
int main ()
{
   char string1[] = "- This is a test string";
   char * character_pointer;
   std::cout << "Splitting stringinto tokens:" << string1 << std::endl;
   character_pointer = strtok (string1," ");
   while (character_pointer != NULL)
   {
       printf ("%s\n", character_pointer);
       character_pointer = strtok (NULL, " ");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `strtok`.  To get exactly what you seem to be
aiming for:

```
std::string const source = "- This is a test string";
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
std::string::const_iterator start = source.begin();
std::string::const_iterator end   = source.end();
std::string::const_iterator next  = std::find( start, end, ' ' );
while ( next != end ) {
    tokens.push_back( std::string( start, next ) );
    start = next + 1;
    next = std::find( start, end, ' ' );
}
tokens.push_back( std::string( start, next ) );
```

Of course, this can be modified as much as you want: you can use
`std::find_first_of` is you want more than one separator, or
`std::search` if you want a multi-character separator, or even
`std::find_if` for an arbitrary test (with a lambda, if you have
C++11).  And in most of the cases where you're parsing, you can
just pass around two iterators, rather than having to construct
a substring; you only need to construct a substring when you
want to save the extracted token somewhere.

Once you get used to using iterators and the standard
algorithms, you'll find it a lot more flexible than `strtok`,
and it doesn't have all of the drawbacks which the internal
state implies.